# Can't Git Push to Mount Folder from Shared Windows Repository (Local Network)

Tags: git, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, git-svn, git-push

I problem in git push, 
i have been mount shared folder from windows like  syntax below:

```
mkdir /mnt/windowsFolder/
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=someusername,password=somepasswrd //WindowsServerIP/RepoFolder /mnt/windowsFolder
```

and then i was clone repo

```
git clone /mnt/windowsFolder/RepoFolder /var/www/html
```

then i pull

```
git pull origin master --------------[success]
```

but when i going to push,
there is the problem. i have some erroe like:

```
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
```

Comment: Check that you have write permission on the mounted folder.

Comment: previously I also think so ...
mounted folder owner is root but when i chown to myusername, still same. owner stil root,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was searching for a few day.. 
and i have been found the answer of my question:
i just mount the shared windows folder with group and user owner:

`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=someusername,password=somepasswrduid=vinra,gid=groups  //WindowsServerIP/RepoFolder /mnt/windowsFolder`

but thanks for @nwinkler for clue